# Django and ManyToMany fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a database in mysql and I am setting up a django project. I have some entities with many-to-many relations, which are handled through association tables. With django, I have understood that I can use ManyToMany entity to achieve many-to-many relations BUT how do I do when the association table holds more information besides just the many-to-many relation?
See the example below.

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(150) DEFAULT NULL ...)

CREATE TABLE `pictures` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` char(100) NOT NULL ... )

CREATE TABLE `products_pictures` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_products_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_pictures_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `priority` tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation` varchar(25) DEFAULT 'same product family' ... )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) option, for example

```
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    pictures = models.ManyToManyField(
        Pictures,
        through='ProductsPictures',
    )

class ProductsPictures(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Pictures, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! What about the Pictures table, should it have the same relation (ManyToMany with through=ProductsPictures)? Or will the possibility to find related records (from Pictures) with Django be created implicitly?

Comment: you will have the opportunity read full page link in the answer, and don't forget to accept the answer if it help you, it will help other people who interest the same question